# How does operator binding work in this Python example?

Tags: python, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I've recently stumbled over this expression:

```
True == False in (False,)
```

It evaluates to `False`, but I don't understand why.
`True == False` is `False` and `False in (False,)` is `True`, so both (to me) plausible possibilities

```
True == (False in (False,))
```

and

```
(True == False) in (False,)
```

evaluate to `True`, as I would have expected.
What is going wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does (1 in \[1,0\] == True) evaluate to False?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284350/why-does-1-in-1-0-true-evaluate-to-false)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is a corner case of Python's comparison-operator chaining. It gets expanded to

```
 (True == False) and (False in (False,))
```

which evaluates to `False`.

This behavior was intended to match conventional math notation (e.g. `x == y == z` meaning that all three are equal, or `0 <= x < 10` meaning `x` is in the range [0, 10)). But `in` is also a comparison operator, giving the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Does this make sense in Python, because I can see what is happening but the in operator has a completely different function to == so why does it undergo this comparison operator chaining?

Comment: `in` is like the others in that it looks at two values and returns a bool, according to the relation between the two values.

Comment: In addition, it is useful to note that this expression is quivalent to `False and True` which will evaluate to `False`, due to [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: @burhan `False and True` evaluates to `False` no matter what -- short circuiting behavior has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Well how about `True and True and False and True`? The last value is never evaluated, which is what I think was @burhan's point.