# Boolean check not working in function

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

This code will be part of a program that will check if a number is prime or not. I know it's not particularly elegant, but I want to get it working simply for experience. I think that the function is failing because the logic on the if/elif is wrong, when I run this code, it seems to just go straight to the else clause. Is this a syntax problem, or am I not allowed to do logic checks in if clauses?

```
list = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]

def find_prime(list, n):
    if n in list == False:
        list.append(n)
        print "I'ts in there now."
    elif n in list == True:
        print "It's in there already."
    else:
        print "Error"

find_prime(list, 3)
find_prime(list, 51)
```

Comment: You should not name a variable `list` Python is already using that identifier.

Comment: Instead of commenting on all the answers, I'll just say thanks here, because all of them worked :)

Comment: This explains your current problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284350/why-does-1-in-1-0-true-evaluate-to-false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `list` is a bad name for a variable. It masks the built-in `list`.
2. `if n in list == True:` doesn't do what you await: `1 in [0, 1] == True` returns `False` (because, as @Duncan notes, `1 in [0,1] == True` is shorthand for `1 in [0,1] and [0,1] == True`). Use `if n in li:` and `if n not in li:`
3. No reason for an `Error`, since an element is in the list or it is not in the list. Anything else is programming error.

So your code could look like this:

```
li = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]

def find_prime(li, n):
    if n in li:
        print "It's in there already."
    else:
        li.append(n)
        print "It's in there now."
```

Comment: Part 2 of your answer is slightly wrong. If it was attempting to test `1 in False` you would get an exception. What actually happens is that `1 in [0,1] == True` is shorthand for `1 in [0,1] and [0,1] == True` and the part after the `and` is False.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code instead of testing for True/False. Also see my comment above regarding using `list` as a variable name (bad idea since that identifier is used by Python).

```
mylist = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]

def find_prime(mylist, n):
    if not n in mylist:
        mylist.append(n)
        print "I'ts in there now."
    else: # n in mylist:  has to be the case
        print "It's in there already."
```

You don't need the original last `else`, your choice is binary, either the number will be in the list or it won't.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call your list [`list`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=list#list). Call it  `mylist` or something else.

Use `if not n in mylist` and `if n in mylist`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the value is either going to be in the list or not, I don't think you need to check three options in your if/else logic.

```
list = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]

def find_prime(list, n):
   if n in list:
      print "It's in there already."
   else:
      list.append(n)
      print "It's in there now."

find_prime(list,3)
find_prime(list,53)
```