# Is there a way to check a number against all numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I was wondering whether you could check a number against all numbers in a list, for example:

```
if n % mylist == 0:
    print "Not Prime"
```

And if you're wondering, this is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629570/boolean-check-not-working-in-function), I hope there's not any rules about question frequency... :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if any(n % x == 0 for x in mylist):
    print "Not Prime"
```

Comment: It's `any()`, not `all()`.  Read the output!

Comment: @SvenMarnach My bad I just looked at the title and answered too quickly

Answer (score 5):

... or even shorter:

```
if not all(n % x for x in mylist):
    print "Not prime"
```

(although I'd prefer jamylak's version - explicit is better than implicit)