# Why does `True == False is False` evaluate to False?

Tags: python

I get some rather unexpected behavior on an expression that works with `==` but not with `is`:

```
>>> (True == False) is False
True
>>> True == (False is False)
True
>>> True == False is False
False
>>> id(True)
8978640
>>> id(False)
8978192
>>> id(True == False)
8978192
>>> id(False is False)
8978640
```

Comment: Oh. Turns out it had nothing to do with `is` vs `==`, as the expression evaluates to `False` in either case. Thanks for all the quick answers!

Comment: @MartijnPieters While typing my answer I thought this must have been asked before, but I guess it can be difficult to google. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284350/why-does-1-in-1-0-true-evaluate-to-false?) could be another duplicate.

Comment: Related to my question: [Why does (1 in [1,0\] == True) evaluate to False?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284350/why-does-1-in-1-0-true-evaluate-to-false)

Comment: I think this would make an excellent interview question for someone who answers "10" to the question "on a scale of 1 to 10, how are your python skills"?

Comment: Why should this evaluate to True ? Absolutely no reason: `True is False` evaluates to False, so does `True == False`, why should `True == False is False` evaluate to True then ?

Comment: @jpic: The spirit of the question, I believe, is that many people will write True == False is False thinking that it will be parsed as (True == False) is False, which evaluates to FALSE is False, and therefore should be True.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Because in fact that's a [chained comparison](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in), so

```
True == False is False
```

is equivalent to

```
(True == False) and (False is False)
```

This can be surprising in this case, but lets you write `1 <= x < 4` unlike in other languages like C.

Comment: (The parenthesis are [never](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) needed, by the way)

Comment: Obviously that's only if they have the same precedence

Comment: @NullUserException Mmm I think they can't be needed because the possible operators are  `"<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "<>" | "!=" | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"` which all have less precedence than `and`. (By the way, thanks for the grammar fix, that really helps us non native speakers).

Comment: And this is exactly why I tend to wrap compound logical comparisons in parens, I simply can't remember the syntax across all the languages I use, and it's not worth the risk of leaving them off and having unexpected behavior.

Comment: @zzzzBov I fully agree, that's why I *did* wrap them ;)

Comment: How do you explain this?
`>>> bool(True == False) is False`
`True`

Comment: @CallMarl `bool(True == False)` evaluates to `False` and since `False` is `False`, the entire expression evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 37):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is
>   evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when
>   x < y is found to be false).

In your case `True == False is False` is equivalent to `True == False and False is False` as the first condition is `False` so it short-circuits and return `False`.

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda : True == False is False)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
              6 DUP_TOP             
              7 ROT_THREE           
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             11 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    21          <---------this step
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
             17 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             20 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   21 ROT_TWO             
             22 POP_TOP             
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: thanks for the dis.dis(). I learned something useful.:)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it seems to me that the description of the language's rules is quite enough to understand what's going on.  The disassembly doesn't seem to add much (other than a focus on implementation-specific details).

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html):

> 5.9. Comparisons
>
> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority, which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise operation. Also unlike C, expressions like a < b < c have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:

```
comparison    ::=  or_expr ( comp_operator or_expr )*
comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "<>" | "!="
                   | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
```

Answer (score 4):

`True == False is False` is a chained comparison, which means the same as `(True == False) and (False is False)`.  Since the first comparison (`True==False`) is false, the result of the chained comparison is False.