# Unintuitive behavior when comparing large numbers

Tags: python, boolean, floating-accuracy, largenumber

Just found some unintuitive behavior while competing in Google CodeJam.

```
input: pow(10, 20) in [pow(10, 20) * 1.0]

output: True
```

(ok...)

```
input: pow(10, 30) in [pow(10, 30) * 1.0]

output: False
```

(???????????)

(so uh, this behavior is dependent on the size of the number?!)

(is this because big Python integers are represented differently behind the scenes?)

```
input: True == True

output: False
```

(ok, all is normal)

```
input: pow(10, 20) in [pow(10, 20) * 1.0] == pow(10, 20) in [pow(10, 20) * 1.0]
```

output: False

(more ?????)

```
input: pow(10, 20) in [pow(10, 20) * 1.0] and pow(10, 20) in [pow(10, 20) * 1.0]
```

output: True

(and I'm totally lost)

Comment: Try `int(1e+30)`, you will be surprised too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of floating point, and also because of the way python handles the result of exponentiation when integers are involved:

```
>>> type(pow(10,30))
<class 'int'>
```

the `pow` operator kept the result as integer.

Now if you multiply by `1.0` you force it to change representation to `float`, and then, with a 30 exponent, the precision isn't enough to compare to the same value as integer.

Unrelated but to fully answer your question, the strange behaviour with `==` is not related: it's a problem of [operator chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284350/why-does-1-in-1-0-true-evaluate-to-false). Using a set of parentheses doesn't hurt and fixes your issue:

```
>>> pow(10, 20) in [pow(10, 20) * 1.0] == pow(10, 20) in [pow(10, 20) * 1.0]
False
>>> (pow(10, 20) in [pow(10, 20) * 1.0]) == (pow(10, 20) in [pow(10, 20) * 1.0])
True
>>>
```