# A question about identity and boolean in Python3

Tags: python, boolean, identity

I have a question about identity in python, i'm a beginner in python and i have read some courses on "is" keyword and "is not". And i don't understand why the operation "False is not True is not True is not False is not True" equals False in python ? For me this operation have to return True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python [chains comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Formally, if `a, b, c, …, y, z` are expressions and `op1, op2, …, opN` are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

Your expression is:

```
False is not True is not True is not False is not True
```

Which becomes:

```
(False is not True) and (True is not True) and (True is not False) and (False is not True)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
(True) and (False) and (True) and (True)
```

Which is `False`.

Comment: The reason I know about this is because the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284350/why-does-1-in-1-0-true-evaluate-to-false) I asked on Stack Overflow, 7 years and 7 months ago, was another incarnation of the question, although at the time I didn't realise it.

Comment: No problem. Done

Answer (score 2):

`is` relates to *identity*.

When you ask `if x is y`, you're really asking *are `x` and `y` the same object*? (Note that this is a different question than *do `x` and `y` have the same value?*)

Likewise when you ask `if x is not y`, you're really asking *are `x` and `y` different objects?*

Specifically in regards to `True` and `False`, Python treats those as *singletons*, which means that there is only ever one `False` object in an entire program.  Anytime you assign somnething to `False`, that is a *reference* to the single `False` object, and so all `False` objects have the same *identity*.

Comment: But aren't `False` and `True` singletons? Or is it just `None` which is? edit: [they are](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/)

Comment: @PeterWood I have updated my answer to address singletons.

Comment: This isn't to do with identity it's to do with how Python chains comparisons.

Answer (score -1):

You are dealing with logic. It helps to think about True = 1 and False = 0.

Think about it this way. 0 is not 1, that will return True because the number 0 is not the number 1 and is a true statment. Same concept with True and False

```
0 is not 1
#this will return False
False is not True
#the computer reads this in the exact same manner.
```