# Explaining the Output of Comparison Expressions Involving Strings and Lists in Python

Tags: python, order-of-execution, in-operator

Hej,

I have the following code snippet and I don't understand the output:

```
a = "foo"
b = "foo"
c = "bar"
foo_list = ["foo", "bar"]


print(a == b in foo_list) # True
print(a == c in foo_list) # False

---
Output: 
True
False
```

The first output is `True`.
I dont understand it because either `a == b` is executed first which results in `True` and then the `in` operation should return `False` as `True` is not in `foo_list`.
The other way around, if `b in foo_list` is executed first, it will return `True` but then `a == True` should return `False`.

I tried setting brackets around either of the two operations, but both times I get `False` as output:

```
print((a == b) in foo_list) # False
print(a == (b in foo_list)) # False
---
Output: 
False
False
```

Can somebody help me out?

Cheers!

Comment: Here’s a question which, I suspect, has the same issue at the bottom: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284350/why-does-1-in-1-0-true-evaluate-to-false/9284410#9284410 .

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thanks @Ture Pålsson.

The answer is *chaining comparisons*.
`a == b in foo_list`is equivalent to `a == b and b in foo_list` where `a==b` is `True` and `b in foo_list` is `True`.
If you set brackets, there will be no chaining.